# Can I remotely change home or lock screens on iPads?

Tags: macos, ipad, mobile-device-management, wallpaper

Is there a way of remotely changing multiple iPad's locks/homescreens to the same custom image all at once over the air (not via USB)? I currently compile profiles with Apple Configurator, but changing wallpaper is apparently not possible with MDM. Isn't there a app or something that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible OTA. You must connect the device over USB to change the wallpapers.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the wallpaper of a supervised iOS device remotely via MDM. There is a "Managed Setting" command available for this.

Here is an excerpt from the Apple MDM documentation.

```
A wallpaper change is a one-time setting that can be changed by the user at will. 
This command is supported in supervised mode only.
```

iOS 9 will also introduce a restriction to forbid changing the wallpaper on supervised devices.

It's just a question if your vendor has implemented it or not.